# Add parameter to String#replace

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to remove the last character from a string if it is a pipe. I have

```
.replace(/\|(\s+)?$/, '')
```

I want to add a parameter `delim` to replace since the last character changes. I am trying:

```
.replace(/\+delim +(\s+)?$/, '')
```

but no luck.

The code that uses this function:

```
 rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString()
     .split(frValues[i][0])
     .join(frValues[i][1]).trim()
     .replace(/\ + delim + (\s+)?$/, '');
```

Comment: The 'change' of the delimiter isn't known? Maybe you could do some conditionals inside () in the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to remove a last character using regex.
- You want to use by changing `delim` in the regex.

If my understanding for your question is correct, how about using RegExp?

#### Modified script:

```
var delim = "|";
var string = "\\" + delim + "(\\s+)?$";
var regex = new RegExp(string);

rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString()
     .split(frValues[i][0])
     .join(frValues[i][1]).trim()
     .replace(regex, '');
```

#### Note :

- When `delim` is `|`, `regex` becomes `/\|(\s+)?$/`.

#### Reference:

- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Einarr I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too!